# Issue with RestKit and CoreData and fetchRequestBlock with predicate (delete orphaned objects)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have an issue with RestKit and the predicate in the fetchRequestBlock to delete orphaned objects. The fetchRequestBlock gets called, but the objects are not deleted.
I have a table "metaData" and a table "product" with a many-to-many relationship. I want RestKit to delete all products with `metaData.qId == 1` and I put this in the predicate of the fetchRequestBlock. If I fetch the data manually with the predicate in the block I get a result of the products that should be deleted. But RestKit does not delete these entries.
Here is my code:

```
[objectManager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL)
 {
     RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"/api/v1/promotions"];
     NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
     BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath]
                      tokenizeQueryStrings:NO
                           parsedArguments:&argsDict];
     if (match)
     {
         NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Product"];
         fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY metaData.qId == 1"];
         fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"productId" ascending:YES] ];             
         return fetchRequest;
     }         
     return nil;
 }];
```

The delete rule in the relationships in Core Data are set to "Nullify". Is there a problem with many-to-many relationships in the fetchRequestBlocks predicate? If I set the predicate to `ANY metaData = nil` RestKit deletes the corresponding entries successfully.

Any ideas? Let me know if you need further information. Thank you for help.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the data in the product table:

```
product table before request (3 entries):
productId = 113362
productId = 136565
productId = 138688

data received by manually executing fetchRequest in the fetchRequestBlock:
productId = 113362
productId = 136565
productId = 138688

new data received from server:
productId = 113362
productId = 112610
productId = 105622

product table after getting data from the server (5 entries):
productId = 113362
productId = 136565
productId = 138688
productId = 112610
productId = 105622
```

Comment: You say that a fetch with the same predicate returns results so the predicate should be fine. What results are you getting from the server though? RestKit will not delete anything that it has just received. Did you debug that `match` is `YES`?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Wain. Yes, `match` is `YES` and I'm executing the fetchRequest here manually. I edited my question and you see the data before, during and after getting data from the server. RestKit should delete at least two entries (136565 and 138688).

Comment: Turn on trace logging for mapping and search for `Fetched local objects matching URL` and `orphaned objects found in local database`. What are they? Are all of these objects saved to the persistent store?